# Smoothing geom_path() with scale_y_reverse() and stat_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset:

```
reading,depth
31055,0.0
57635,0.5
34268,1.0
20926,1.5
13507,2.0
12944,2.5
13002,3.0
12892,3.5
12610,4.0
12158,4.5
12004,5.0
```

I'm plotting an instrument reading as a function of below-ground depth. Because of what I'm visualizing, I want the axes to have a non-standard configuration, like this:

```
ggplot(data=f0101, aes(x=reading, y=depth)) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_y_reverse() + 
    scale_x_continuous(position="top") + 
    geom_path()
```

[image: img1]

This is perfect, except that I'd like the line smoothed, via stat_smooth() or similar. But, calling a smooth appears to throw off geom_path().

```
ggplot(data=f0101, aes(x=reading, y=depth)) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_y_reverse() + 
    scale_x_continuous(position="top") + 
    geom_path() + 
    stat_smooth()
```

[image: img2]

What can I do to get the smoothing effect of stat_smooth() while still plotting the data in an admittedly non-standard configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: The `geom_smooth()` really isn't throwing off the `geom_path()` at all. it's changing the scale of the `y` axis which gives the *appearance* of throwing it off, but that's it.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but I think you *probably* want something like this:

```
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = reading)) +
  geom_path() +
  stat_smooth() +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "top") +
  coord_flip()
```

which produces

[image]

For this, you're running the smooth with depth on the `x` and reading on the `y`, then flipping the coordinates.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @puzzledkiwi Feel free to click the little check mark underneath the up and down arrows to "accept" the answer. Glad I could help!